# Url Rewrite with Web.config not working with IIS express

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-express

I need to use Url Rewriting, so I made a test case, in Web.config, to check if it's working:

**Web.config:**

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Fail bad requests">
      <match url=".*"/>
      <action type="AbortRequest" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
... other stuff
</system.webServer>
```

I was expecting any `localhost:3285` to abort and fail, but it entered correctly.

I'm using [Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) with IIS Express.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing your problem is browser caching.  I have found that if I open a web page in IE, then add URL rewrite rules (requires stopping IIS express), then open the same page again in IE it still loads the page (and it appears the abort rule is not being applied).  But, if I clear the IE browser cache and refresh the page the abort occurs.

Here is a full `Web.config` example that works for me

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Fail bad requests">
          <match url=".*"/>
          <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Your example should work because the URL rewrite module is built into the current version of IIS Express:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview